# Visual Studio 2012 strange characters at beginning of file

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2012

Whenever i copy a file made in VS2012 over to Eclipse, and open the file in Eclipse doc viewer there always seem to be some extra characters at the beginning (pic below).  They arent visible in VS2012, or if I open the file in Notepad.  What character is that being put there, and how can i get it to stop?  Below is a pic of a JS file I made i VS, and how it appears in Eclipse [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats a UTF8 BOM, Ive heard thgis works well for windows

http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm

If you have access to linux you can use awk to remove